# C# GUI on top of C hard calculation engine

Tags: c#, c, windows, performance

Some time ago, I developed a mathematical plotter in C# that draws functions in various geometrical spaces through old, "dumb", numerical calculations.
The users simply inserts an n-variable equation or curve that is simplified and semicompiled, then calculated for the entire set of combinations of values of the variables  in the domain, and then displayed.

I'm working on optimization at the algorithm to reduce calculations, however as far I can see there’s no way, for the problems I have to manage, to go under at least 5*10^7 operations, that in least powerful machines and in C# machine code results a 1-1.5 seconds lag, that is unacceptable, at least since the same code implemented in C is 20x faster (and  that’s only the unoptimized version!).

So what I would like to do is modify my application keeping a good 80% of the old C# "slow" code, GUI included, leaving therefore the calculation and rendering part to "fast" C. The "slow" part must pass a strings and some int params to the "fast" engine, and receive back int or byte arrays  of the order of 1Mb. I read that there are a lot of ways to make this on windows (put the C in a dll called by the main c# app via P/Invoke, build two different executables “talking” through pipes or sockets, shared memory, Data Copy, etc. etc.), but I found very few comparisons between them.

The criteria are 1) manly performance (less data exchange lag wins), 2) simplicity and ability to keep the C code more pure and plain as is possible (no hybrid languages like c++/cli).

So, which is the best strategy to solve the problem?

Comment: C++ is just object oriented C it is not memory managed like C#. So C++(in its pure form) has the benefits of C but makes it easier to work with than structural/procedural C. However this all academic.My suggestions is to test some of these yourself with a small project. I know there can be some thorny issues with DLL's and C# but I mainly work in Java,C,C++ so cant really voice an experts opinion.

Comment: I don't think shared memory (IPC) would be a good fit (it rarely is). Why not just create/find a C library to do these calculations, and export them to a shared library (DLL)? C# can then interface with these functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're not that elaborating on the computation it is hard to tell what is the best approach for you. 
Have you used all possible "mathematical tricks" (It has been time since I studied numeric analysis at the university but there are excellent books around that). 
If you want to call C code from your application, bare in mind two things: 
A. If you use IPC, it can slow things down, unless you will make one call for input, and then get the output, don't make X calls from Process A to Process B. 
B. If you use one process (C# calling C, this is possible in Java using JNI/JNA, and I know it is possible in C# as well), make sure that your C code is "stable", as if it crashes, then your C# part will crash too (in the first approach only the "C process" crashes while the C# process is alive (and the "C process" can be clustered or can be automatically started up using watchdog).